# Проблема разбора [#if ??]

Tags: java, freemarker

Некорректно работаeт FreeMarker.

Указал:

`setInterpolationSyntax(Configuration.SQUARE_BRACKET_INTERPOLATION_SYNTAX)`

```
...
<h1>Welcome [=user]!</h1>
<p>Our latest product:
    <a href="[=latestProduct.url]">[=latestProduct.name]</a>
    <h3>[#if latestProduct.serviceName??] Exist config_fp_name: '[=latestProduct.serviceName]' [/#if]</h3>
...
</html>
```

В результате конструкция частично отрабатывается, однако `if` игнорируется (с синтаксисом треугольных скобок `<if ??>` такой проблемы нет):

```
<h1>Welcome Big Joe!</h1>
<p>Our latest product:
    <a href="products/greenmouse.html">green mouse</a>
    <h3>[#if latestProduct.serviceName??] Exist config_fp_name: 'serviceName' [/#if]</h3>
```

Почему так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterpolationSyntax` влияет только на интерполяцию переменных, то есть это только для того, чтоб указать какой синтаксис для переменных использовать: `[=x]` или `${x}`.

Для тегов (типа `if`) используйте [setTagSyntax](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/api/freemarker/template/Configuration.html#setTagSyntax-int-):

```
setTagSyntax(Configuration.SQUARE_BRACKET_TAG_SYNTAX);
```

В [документации](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_misc_alternativesyntax.html) это описано:

> the interpolation syntax can be configured to be like [=x] instead of ${x}. Also, independently of that, the FreeMarker tag syntax can be configured to use [], like in [#if x]...[/#if].